# Convert streamed PNG data to image: data Streamed via TCP using UnrealEngine 4.10

Tags: c#, tcp, streaming, unreal-engine4

I have created a small application using UnrealEngine 4.10 (UE4). Within that application, I am grabbing the colorBuffer via ReadPixels. I am then compressing the colorBuffer to PNG. Finally, the compressed colorBuffer is sent via TCP to another application. The UE4 application is written in c++, not that that should matter. **The compressed colorBuffer is being sent every "tick" of the application - essentially 30 times a second (thereabouts).**

My client, the one receiving the streamed PNG is written in c# and does the following:

- Connect to server If connected
- get the stream (memory stream)
- read the memory stream into a byte array
- convert the byte array to an image

Client implementation:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var connected = tcp.IsConnected();

    if (connected)
    {
       var stream = tcp.GetStream(); //simply returns client.GetStream();
       int BYTES_TO_READ = 16; 
       var buffer = new byte[BYTES_TO_READ];
       var totalBytesRead = 0;
       var bytesRead;
       do {
           // You have to do this in a loop because there's no            
           // guarantee that all the bytes you need will be ready when 
           // you call.
           bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, totalBytesRead,   
                                   BYTES_TO_READ - totalBytesRead);
           totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
       } while (totalBytesRead < BYTES_TO_READ);

       Image x = byteArrayToImage(buffer);

    }
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
   var converter = new ImageConverter();
   Image img = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(byteArrayIn);
   return img;
 }
```

The problem is that `Image img = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(byteArrayIn);`

Throws an argument exception, telling me "**Parmeter is not valid**".

The data being sent looks like this:
[image]

My `byteArrayIn`and `buffer` look like this:
[image]

I have also tried both:
`Image.FromStream(stream);` and `Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes));`

`Image.FromStream(stream);` causes it to read forever... and `Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes));` results in the same exception as mentioned above.

**Some questions:**

1. What size shall I set `BYTES_TO_READ` to be? I set as 16 because when I check the size of the byte array being sent in the UE4 application (`dataSize` in the first image), it says the length is 16... Not too sure about what to set this as.
2. Is the process that I have followed correct?

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

@RonBeyer asked if I could verify that the data sent from the server matches that which is received. I have tried to do that and here is what I can say:

The data sent, as far as I can tell looks like this (sorry for formatting): 
[image]

The data being received, looks like this:

```
var stream = tcp.GetStream();

int BYTES_TO_READ = 512;
var buffer = new byte[BYTES_TO_READ];

Int32 bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
var responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, 
                                                        bytes);

//responseData looks like this (has been formatted for easier reading)
//?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR
//?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR
//?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR
//?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR
//?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR
//?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR
//?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR
//?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR
//?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR
//?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR
```

If I try take a single line from the responseData and put that into an image:

```
  var stringdata = "?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR";
  var data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringdata);
  var ms = new MemoryStream(data);
  Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

`data` has a length of 16... the same length as the `dataSize` variable on the server. However, I again get the execption "Parameter is not valid".

**UPDATE 2**

@Darcara has helped by suggesting that what I was actually receiving was the header of the PNG file and that I needed to first send the size of the image. I have now done that and made progress:

```
for (TArray<class FSocket*>::TIterator ClientIt(Clients); ClientIt; 
                                                          ++ClientIt)
{
    FSocket *Client = *ClientIt;

    int32 SendSize = 2 * x * y;
    Client->SetNonBlocking(true);
    Client->SetSendBufferSize(SendSize, SendSize);
    Client->Send(data, SendSize, bytesSent);
}
```

With this, I am now getting the image on the first go, however, subsequent attempts fail with the same "Parameter is not valid". Upon inspection, I have noticed that the stream now appears to be missing the header... `"?PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR"`. I came to this conclusion when I converted the buffer to a string using `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);`

Any idea why the header is now only being sent to first time and never again? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure that is the proper use of `ImageConverter`. Have you tried just creating the `Image` from a `MemoryStream` constructed from the byte array?

Comment: @RonBeyer Can you elaborate? I tried Image.FromStream as mentioned above. Is that what you mean? I passed a memory stream to FromStream.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Did you get an exception when you tried that? Also, have you verified that the data you receive matches the data that is sent, and wasn't byte-swapped or anything?

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't get any execption when I try Image.FromStream(stream). The breakpoint hits it and then nothing happens... despite being within a Timer_Tick event and being called every 100ms. I am not sure how to verify that the data sent is the data received - I tried to do that and please see the updated question.

Comment: @RonBeyer I forgot to mention that the client, besides nothing happening past the break point, becomes unresponsive.

Comment: If you've found a solution to your problem *post is as an answer* don't edit it into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank you to @Dacara and @RonBeyer for your help.

I now have a solution:

**Server:**

```
for (TArray<class FSocket*>::TIterator ClientIt(Clients); ClientIt; 
                                                          ++ClientIt)
{
    FSocket *Client = *ClientIt;

    int32 SendSize = x * y; // Image is 512 x 512 
    Client->SetSendBufferSize(SendSize, SendSize);
    Client->Send(data, SendSize, bytesSent);
}
```

The first issue was that the size of the image needed to be correct:

```
 int32 SendSize = 2 * x * y;
```

The line above is wrong. The image is `512 by 512` and so `SendSize` should be `x * y` where x & y are both 512.

The other issue was how I was handling the stream client side.

**Client:**

```
var connected = tcp.IsConnected();

if (connected)
{
    var stream = tcp.GetStream();

    var BYTES_TO_READ = (512 * 512)^2;
    var buffer = new byte[BYTES_TO_READ];

    var bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, BYTES_TO_READ);

    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer));

    //Apply the image to a picture box. Note, this is running on a separate 
    //thread.
    UpdateImageViewerBackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, returnImage);
 }
```

The `var BYTES_TO_READ = (512 * 512)^2;` is now the correct size.

I now have Unreal Engine 4 streaming its frames.

Answer (score 0):

You are only reading the first 16 bytes of the stream. I'm guessing that is not intentional.

If the stream ends/connection closes after the image is transferred, use `stream.CopyTo` to copy it into a `MemoryStream`. `Image.FromStream(stream)` might also work

If the stream does not end, you need to know the size of the transferred object beforehand, so you can copy it read-by-read into another array / memory stream or directly to disk. In that case a much higher read buffer should be used (default is 8192 I think). This is a lot more complicated though.

To manually read from the stream, you need to prepend you data with the size. A simple Int32 should suffice. Your client code might look something like this:

```
var stream = tcp.GetStream();
//this is our temporary read buffer
int BYTES_TO_READ = 8196; 
var buffer = new byte[BYTES_TO_READ];
var bytesRead;

//read size of data object
stream.Read(buffer, 0, 4);  //read  4 bytes into the beginning of the empty buffer
//TODO: check that we actually received 4 bytes.
var totalBytesExpected = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0)
//this will be the stream we will save our received bytes to
//could also be a file stream
var imageStream = new MemoryStream(totalBytesExpected);

var totalBytesRead = 0;
do {
    //read as much as the buffer can hold or the remaining bytes
    bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(BYTES_TO_READ, totalBytesExpected - totalBytesRead));
    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    //write bytes to image stream
    imageStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   } while (totalBytesRead < totalBytesExpected );
```

I glossed over a lot of error handling here, but that should give you the general idea.

If you want to transfer more complex objects look into proper protocols like [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/)

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and `var imageStream = new MemoryStream(totalBytesExpected);` throws an OutOfMemoryException ;(

Comment: That means `totalBytesExpected` is too large. Either you are not sending the size of the png as a 4 byte integer directly before sending the png from your c++ code, or de/serialization failed (endianess?). What value does `totalBytesExpected` have?

Comment: @Dacara I have tried changing the size, but I always get the error. The size of `totalBytesExpected` is `1196314761`.

Comment: That number is the beginning of the png header. You must send the size of the png prior to sending the png itself.

Comment: @Dacara Thank you, you've helped a great deal. However, now that I get the image on the first attempt, the subsequent attempts to read the stream result in error because the data received no longer contains the header! I have posted an update (UPDATE 2) and would appreciate a little more help ;)